# Undefined method when trying to load partial in infowindow googlemaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm using the GoogleMaps4Rails gem and I'm trying to edit the marker.infowindow. I want to put a partial inside the window when they click on marker.

This is what my posts controller looks like:

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@posts) do |posts, marker|
      marker.lat posts.latitude
      marker.lng posts.longitude
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "show", :locals => { :object => posts})
      marker.picture({
        "url" => "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
        "width" => 32,
        "height" => 32
      })
end
```

And my partial (_show.html.erb) looks like this:

```
<p>
  <strong>Latitude:</strong>
  <%= @post.latitude %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Longitude:</strong>
  <%= @post.longitude %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @post.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= @post.description %>
</p>
```

The problem is, I get this error when I try to load the page:

```
undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass
<p>
  <strong>Latitude:</strong>
  <%= @post.latitude %>
</p>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should resolve it:

```
<p>
  <strong>Latitude:</strong>
  <%= object.latitude %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Longitude:</strong>
  <%= object.longitude %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= object.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
  <%= object.description %>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply dimakura! I had no idea it was that easy. it works!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how how to add a button that goes to the posts show page. I tried <%= link_to 'Show', post %> with no luck.

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Show', object %>` should work, otherwise I need to see your `routes.rb` file